# Is it possible to fetch datasource and personalized content of context item?

Tags: personalization

Context Item- mypage
-- Presentation
----Controller Rendering -R1 with datasource value -D1
-----R1- Personalize Content.D2

How do I refer both these data content and get it rendered in given page context?

Let me know if queries or require more explanation.

Comment: You want both the personalized datasource (A/B testing) and the original datasource?

Comment: Yes i need both

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to be rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time the below code is accessed in Controller/View Rendering, any personlization rules are applied.

> So, the `DataSource` and `Item` properties point to the the datasource are the personalized ones configured for the rule that is applied.

```
Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource
Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item
```

Below code shows how to get the RuleList xml and pull the default DataSource out of it.

```
string text = rendering.Properties["RenderingXml"];
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
   {
     var renderingReference =  
     new RenderingReference(XmlExtensions.ToXmlNode(XElement.Parse(text)), <contextlanguage>, <contextdatabase>);

     var DefaultDataSource = renderingreference.Settings.DataSource;
   }
```

[image: Rendering xml with personalization rules]

Once the Rendering reference is obtained, the default datasource can be pulled from its `Settings.DataSource` property.

[image]

The order of DataSource for the rendering will be

> 1. DataSource selected in the Action section of Rule that is applied
> 2. The order of Default DataSource will be
>
>    - DS selected in the Action section
>    - If Action Section is empty, then DS selected from Rendering Parameters
>    - If none of them are set then `RenderingReference.Settings.DataSource` is empty. But the actual Rendering DataSource set to PageItem

Comment: Could you please clarify in your answer: 1) How to get the original data source? 2) How to get the personalized data source?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko updated my answer. 1) By default the datasource provided to the Rendering is Personalized datasource based on Rule applied. 2) I added code section to pull the Default DataSource from Rules XML for reference.

Comment: @Santosh You can inherit the `Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.Personalize, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics` class and override the `RunRules` method to attach an event when the rule is applied `rules.Applied+= new RuleActionEventHandler<ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext>(<yourmethod>)`. When the rules are processed this event will get executed. You can store the default datasource during this time into the Rendering parameters and use it later in your View/Controller.

Comment: Thanks Phani, this is what i m looking for. I'll try this.